# ReGex patten to match <c:if > conditional variable names?

Tags: java, regex, jsp

I need to get conditional variable name for all cases in a particular jsp
I am reading the jsp line by line and searching for particular pattern like for a line  say its checking two type of cond where it finds the match

```
       <c:if condition="Event ='Confirmation'">
       <c:if condition="Event1 = 'Confirmation' or Event2 = 'Action'or Event3 = 'Check'" .....>
```

**Desired Result** is name of all cond variable - **Event,Event1,Event2,Event3** I have written a parser that only satisfying the first case But not able to find variable names for second case.Need a pattern to satisfy both of them.

```
    String stringSearch = "<c:if";
    while ((line = bf.readLine()) != null) {
                // Increment the count and find the index of the word
                lineCount++;
                int indexfound = line.indexOf(stringSearch);

                if (indexfound > -1) {

                    Pattern pattern = Pattern
                            .compile(test=\"([\\!\\(]*)(.*?)([\\=\\)\\s\\.\\>\\[\\(]+?));

                    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(line);
                    if (matcher.find()) {

                        str = matcher.group(1);
                        hset.add(str);
                        counter++;

                    }
                }
```

Comment: Yeah, compile pattern each iteration of your loop...

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your requirement well, this may work :

```
("|\s+)!?(\w+?)\s*=\s*'.*?'
```

`$2` will give each condition variable name.

What it does is:

`("|\s+)` a **"** or **one or more spaces**

`!?` an optional **!**

`(\w+?)` one or more word character (letter, digit or underscore) (`([A-Za-z]\w*)` would be more correct)

`\s*=\s*` an **=** preceded and followed by zero or more spaces

`'.*?'` zero or more characters inside **'** and **'**

Second capture group is (\w+?) retrieving the variable name

Add required escaping for `\`

**Edit:** For the additional conditions you specified, the following may suffice:

```
("|or\s+|and\s+)!?(\w+?)(\[\d+\]|\..*?)?\s*(!?=|>=?|<=?)\s*.*?
```

`("|or\s+|and\s+)` A **"** or an **or** followed by one or more spaces or an **and** followed by one or more spaces. (Here, it is assumed that each expression part or variable name is preceded by a **"** or an **or** followed by one or more spaces or an **and** followed by one or more spaces)

`!?(\w+?)` An optional **!** followed by one or more word character

`(\[\d+\]|\..*?)?` An optional part constituting **a number enclosed in square brackets** or **a dot followed by zero or more characters**

`(!?=|>=?|<=?)` Any of the following relational operators : =,!=,>,<,>=,<=

`$2` will give the variable name.

Here second capture group is `(\w+?)` retrieving variable name and third capture group retrieves any suffix if present (eg:`[2]` in `Event[2]`).

For input containing a condition `Event.indexOf(2)=something`, `$2` gives `Event` only. If you want it to be `Event.indexOf(2)` use `$2$3`.

Comment: First of all  I need to consider "test=" because there could be other attributes in jsp so need to fetch only for "test".
Second a variable name contains special char also like  arr[1]=23 or it can be Boolean like !var and cond are can be varied like >,!=,< etc

Comment: @PramitBhaumik your examples didn't mention that.

Comment: @PramitBhaumik it will be helpful if you add some examples showing your requirements.

Comment: @Naveed...u can consider variables like
 <c:if condition="Event1[9] ='Confirmation' or Event2 != 'Action' or !Event or Event3>=20 or Event.indexOf(2)='value'....> these conditions can be occur in single state also with logical op like
 <c:if condition="Eve

Comment: @PramitBhaumik check whether the edited answer meets your requirement

Answer (score 0):

This could suit your needs:

```
"(\\w+)\\s*=\\s*(?!\")"
```

Which means:

```
Every word followed by a = that isn't followed by a "
```

For example:

```
String s = "<c:if condition=\"Event ='Confirmation'\"><c:if condition=\"Event1 = 'Confirmation' or Event2 = 'Action'or Event3 = 'Check'\" .....>";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\w+)\\s*=\\s*(?!\")");
Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
}
```

Prints:

```
Event
Event1
Event2
Event3
```